# How to set up reCaptcha with BootstrapValidator

Tags: recaptcha

I have a Bootstrap 3 form using BootstrapValidator (http://bootstrapvalidator.com). I managed to get the reCaptcha to show up on my form above the submit button but I can not figure out how to get the validator to check the reCaptcha. I just don't understand the recaptcha_check_answer function.

Here is my BootstrapValidator script:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
    // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        first_name: {
            validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                    min: 2,
                },
                    notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your first name'
                }
            }
        },
         last_name: {
            validators: {
                 stringLength: {
                    min: 2,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your last name'
                }
            }
        },
        email: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your email address'
                },
                emailAddress: {
                    message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
                }
            }
        },
        phone: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your phone number'
                },
                phone: {
                    country: 'US',
                    message: 'Please supply a vaild phone number with area code'
                }
            }
        },
        address: {
            validators: {
                 stringLength: {
                    min: 8,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your street address'
                }
            }
        },
        city: {
            validators: {
                 stringLength: {
                    min: 4,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your city'
                }
            }
        },
        state: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please select your state'
                }
            }
        },
        zip: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your zip code'
                },
                zipCode: {
                    country: 'US',
                    message: 'Please supply a vaild zip code'
                }
            }
        },
        comment: {
            validators: {
                  stringLength: {
                    min: 10,
                    max: 200,
                    message:'Please enter at least 10 characters and no more than 200'
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply a description of your project'
                }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow") // Do something ...
            $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

This is my form processing PHP file:

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "MyPrivateKey";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
   //--------------------------Set these paramaters--------------------------

// Subject of email sent to you.
$subject = 'Quote Form Response';

// Your email address. This is where the form information will be sent.
$emailadd = 'myemail';

// From email address. This is who the form information will be sent from.
$email_from = $_POST['email'];

// Where to redirect after form is processed.
$url = 'javascript://history.go(-1)';

// Makes all fields required. If set to '1' no field can not be empty. If set to '0' any or all fields can be empty.
$req = '0';

// --------------------------Do not edit below this line--------------------------
$text = "Results from Quote form:\n\n";
$space = ' ';
$line = '
';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
if ($req == '1')
{
if ($value == '')
{echo "$key is empty";die;}
}
$j = strlen($key);
if ($j >= 20)
{echo "Name of form element $key cannot be longer than 20 characters";die;}
$j = 20 - $j;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++)
{$space .= ' ';}
$value = str_replace('\n', "$line", $value);
$conc = "{$key}:$space{$value}$line";
$text .= $conc;
$space = ' ';
}
mail($emailadd, $subject, $text, 'From: '.$email_from.'');
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
  ?>
```

This is the form working with just the BootstrapValidator plugin http://codepen.io/jaycbrf/pen/iBszr

Please help me figure this out, I got 14 spams last night and my cell phone went off for every one starting at 4am...

thanks.

Comment: any solution to this?